# JPA : OneToMany, get set of children of the owner entity

Tags: java, jpa, one-to-many

I have those two entities :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "commande")
public class Commande implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "commande")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<Piece> pieces = new HashSet<>();



@Entity
@Table(name = "piece")
public class Piece implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "ref")
    private String ref;

    @ManyToOne
    private Commande commande;
```

When I load the entity Commande, I would like its property pieces not to be empty if there are pieces linked to this commande.
How can I achieve that?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "When I load the entity Commande"? Load it in the code? Does everything look OK in the database, and you still don't get any results? The mapping looks OK.

Comment: When I am getting all the entities Commande from my database, I can't access to the pieces property, I am getting a 'com.sun.jdi.InvocationException occurred invoking method' . In my database, table Piece has a foreign key to Commande.

Comment: Edit the question with the entire exception, and other relevant information

Comment: you mean you want EAGER fetching of the related objects? so set Fetch to EAGER?!

Comment: EAGER will automatically load all the pieces right? what if I want to decide if I want to load the pieces or not (depending on the use case)?